# Why do I have problems constructing a complicated GUI using Perl-Tk on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, memory, perltk

I have a Perl-Tk GUI with about 50 sub-windows. In each sub-window there are about 50 buttons and 50 menus (each menu has about 4 options).

When I run it on UNIX/Linux/Solaris, it runs smoothly.

When I run it on Windows, the GUI freezes in the middle of loading so I see only some of the buttons, or the GUI doesn't show at all — it seems stuck.

The perl process comes up to 50000K mem usage and 100% CPU usage.
But when I take some of the buttons/menus off and run again — it's fine.

So it seems, the Perl-Tk doesn't get (have) enough memory to load the GUI on windows.

Is there anything I can do to make it run correctly? Are there any special configurations, flags to tell windows to give Perl-TK some more memory, or to tell perl to come up with more memory?

Any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: This may be flagged as 'not helpful', but I guess a UI with 50 buttons is a usability nightmare. Have you considered restructuring your GUI?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get some details regarding the underlying problem is to profile the code

```
perl -d:DProf <your program name>
```

This will give you complete details regarding the behaviour of your program.

You can then go ahead and tweak the code that is causing this erroneous behaviour.

This will lead us in the right direction.